# Problem in receiving Future data (SharedPreferences) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, future

I am trying to save the value of `Switch` in SharedPreferences. Here is my code :

```
  bool isDarkTheme;
  static const String KEY_DARK_THEME = "dark";

  void setTheme(bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isDarkTheme = value;
    pref.setBool(KEY_DARK_THEME, isDarkTheme);
    print("DARKSet? $isDarkTheme");
  }

  void getTheme() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isDarkTheme = sharedPreferences.getBool(KEY_DARK_THEME);
    print("dark? $isDarkTheme");
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print("MYINIT");
    getTheme();
  }
```

And inside Build method...

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("BUILD $isDarkTheme");
    ...
    ...
    ListTile(
      title: Text("Dark Theme"),
      trailing: Switch(
      value: isDarkTheme ?? false,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          setTheme(val);
        });
      },
      ),
    ),
    ...
    ...
 }
```

Though I get the correct value inside debug console, but Switch widget is not changed accordingly. I found `build()` method is run before getting the value from `SharedPrefernces`, as a result Switch widget is not getting value from SharedPreferences. How to solve this problem of receiving `Future` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two option

1). I think when you get value from SharedPreference at that time you just call setState() method

```
 void getTheme() async {
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() {
    isDarkTheme = sharedPreferences.getBool(KEY_DARK_THEME);
    print("dark? $isDarkTheme");
  });}
```

2) You can use Provider for StateManagement so, when isDarkTheme value is changed notifyListener is called and your build method is rebuild and you see the change

Comment: Tried the first option and its working! +1 for that. But I am still confused about accurate way of receiving Future inside build method.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that you're retrieving the `SharedPreferences` instance whenever you want to store or retrieve a value, beside the fact you're also using two instances of it (`pref` and `sharedPreferences`) :

retrieve a single `SharedPreferences` instance using a separate function:

```
 SharedPreferences pref ;

 Future loadPreferences() async {
   pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 }
```

Then modify `getTheme` and `setTheme` :

```
 void setTheme(bool value) async {
   isDarkTheme = value;
   pref.setBool(KEY_DARK_THEME, isDarkTheme);
   print("DARKSet? $isDarkTheme");
 }

 void getTheme() async {
   isDarkTheme = pref.getBool(KEY_DARK_THEME);
   print("dark? $isDarkTheme");
 }
```

Also, call `loadPreferences` during initialization, so `pref` will be loaded by the time `build` is called:

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   print("MYINIT");
   loadPreferences().then((_){
      getTheme();
    }); 
 }
```

Comment: Not working, still the build() method is run before getting the value from SharedPrefernces.